# Need to remove Elastic behaviour in parallax effect when using Android Design Library

Tags: android, android-design-library

I am using android design support library to achieve parallax effect with recycler view at bottom.When I pull down then animation is having elastic behavior which  I do not want.I want smooth animation for scroll up and scroll down.

Comment: Can you post your XML?